# Recover the timer of an other instance in order to modify its properties

Tags: c#, timer

I have two projects in a solution, the first one is the client and the second is the service.

In the service, there is a timer which is initialized.

I would like to modify the properties (e.g.:interval) of the timer via the client.

The issue is that I've not access to the timer initialized by the service via the client because they are two different instances.

For the moment, I modify the properties of the timer in the database via the client and the service reads and adapts it on the event elapsed of the timer before the treatment. Therefore, if I want to reduce the interval from 40 hours to 5 seconds, I have to wait for the following event elapsed. That can be long ...

Do you have an idea ?